# Typecscript and Angular error with argument types

Tags: angular, typescript

How to correct this error that I get in Angular:

```
(response: HttpResponse<User>) => {
```

gives error of:

```
Argument of type '(response: HttpResponse<User>) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: HttpResponse<User> | HttpErrorResponse) => void'.
  Types of parameters 'response' and 'value' are incompatible.
    Type 'HttpResponse<User> | HttpErrorResponse' is not assignable to type 'HttpResponse<User>'.
      Type 'HttpErrorResponse' is missing the following properties from type 'HttpResponse<User>': body, clone
```

AND

`(response.body);` gives error of

```
Argument of type 'User | null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'User'.
  Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'User'.
```

I am using typescript 4.5.5 in Angular.

The function is:

```
public onLogin(user: User): void{
    console.log(user)
    this.subscriptions.push(
      this.authenticationService.login(user).subscribe(
        (response: HttpResponse<User>) => {
          const token: string = response.headers.get(HeaderType.JWT_TOKEN) || '';
          this.authenticationService.saveToken(token);
          this.authenticationService.addUserToLocalCache(response.body);
          this.router.navigateByUrl('/dashboard');
        },
        (error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
          console.log(error);
          this.sendErrorNotification(NotificationType.ERROR, error.error.message);
        }
      )
    );
  }
```

NOTE: I had previously used this function in another project with a different typescript version and did not have these issues.

Comment: Did you try `(response: HttpResponse<User>| HttpErrorResponse) => { `

Comment: Thanks. That solves the first error.

Comment: For the second error I now get ```Property 'body' does not exist on type 'HttpResponse<User> | HttpErrorResponse'.
  Property 'body' does not exist on type 'HttpErrorResponse'.```

Comment: are you sure the login() method returns Observable<HttpResponse<User>| HttpErrorResponse>?

Comment: Hi, can share us the `login` method for `authenticationService`? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**Issue 1**

What I suspect from the `login` method in `AuthenticationService` is that you are returning `Observable<HttpResponse<User> | HttpErrorResponse>` as similar code below:

```js
login(user: User) {
  return (
    this.httpClient
      .post<HttpResponse<User>>(/* Login API url */, user)
      .pipe(catchError((err) => this.handleError(err)))
  );
}

handleError(err: HttpErrorResponse) {
  return of(err);
}
```

---

**Solution for Issue 1**

While to *return* error from an `Observable` so that another subscription to able to get it, you need [(rxjs) `throwError`](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/throwError):

```js
import { throwError } from 'rxjs';

login(user: User) {
  return (
    this.httpClient
      .post<HttpResponse<User>>(/* Login API url */, user)
      .pipe(catchError((err) => this.handleAndThrowError(err)))
  );
}

handleAndThrowError(err: HttpErrorResponse) {
  return throwError(err);
}
```

---

**Issue 2**

From [`HttpResponse<T>`](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpResponse),

```js
class HttpResponse<T> extends HttpResponseBase {
  constructor(init: { body?: T; headers?: HttpHeaders; status?: number; statusText?: string; url?: string; } = {})
  body: T | null

  ...
}
```

The `response.body` is possibly `null`.

---

**Solution for Issue 2**

You can perform the null checking for `response.body` with:

```js
if (response.body)
  this.authenticationService.addUserToLocalCache(response.body);
```

[Sample Demo in StackBlitz (with multiple scenarios)](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-aqkzid?file=src/app/authentication.service.ts)